STM32H7 Baremetal UART DMA Rx not working - DMA tx works
I have a STM32H7 running UART. UART TX works fine, and it's definetely not a D-Cache problem, I already have configured the MPU correctly and in another project DMA works just fine with SPI with the same memory configuration.
I am trying to receive data in a buffer and then process the data in the receiver timeout interrupt. The interrupt works just fine - it's not a pin or UART configuration problem either.
Here is the DMA initialization code for RX:
// === DMA RX ===
RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_DMA2EN;
DMA2_Stream1->PAR = (uint32_t) &(USART1->RDR);
DMA2_Stream1->M0AR = (uint32_t) uart_rx_buf;
DMA2_Stream1->M1AR = (uint32_t) uart_rx_buf;
DMA2_Stream1->NDTR = UART_RX_SIZE;

DMA2_Stream1->CR = 0;
DMA2_Stream1->CR |= DMA_SxCR_CIRC;
DMA2_Stream1->CR |= (0u << DMA_SxCR_DIR_Pos);   // Peripheral to memory
DMA2_Stream1->CR |= DMA_SxCR_MINC;   // Memory increment mode
DMA2_Stream1->CR |= (3u << DMA_SxCR_PL_Pos);   // Very High priority

DMA2_Stream1->CR |= 0b00 << DMA_SxCR_MSIZE_Pos; // Byte ( 8 Bits)
DMA2_Stream1->CR |= 0b00 << DMA_SxCR_PSIZE_Pos; // Byte ( 8 Bits)


DMAMUX1_Channel9->CCR = 41; // UART1 RX mux chan
DMA2_Stream1->CR |= DMA_SxCR_EN;

And here is the UART init code:
// === UART 1 ===
MODIFY_REG(RCC->D2CCIP2R, RCC_D2CCIP2R_USART16SEL_Msk, (0b01) << RCC_D2CCIP2R_USART16SEL_Pos); // PLL2Q clock source
RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_USART1EN;

USART1->RTOR = 100;
MODIFY_REG(USART1->CR1, USART_CR1_M_Msk | USART_CR1_PCE | USART_CR1_PS, USART_CR1_RE | USART_CR1_TE | USART_CR1_RTOIE);
MODIFY_REG(USART1->CR2, USART_CR2_STOP, (0 << USART_CR2_STOP_Pos) | USART_CR2_RTOEN) ;
USART1->CR3 |= USART_CR3_DMAR | USART_CR3_OVRDIS;
USART1->BRR = 100UL;

USART1->CR1 |= USART_CR1_UE;

For some reason, DMA2_Stream1->NDTR always equals it's start value - UART_RX_SIZE, and there are no error flags, as if no DMA requests ever occured. What am I doing wrong?

Read out and check/post content of UART and relevant DMA/DMAMUX registers.
